# Hyperlink Excel to html specific information (linked) on a web-page is not working

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink

If i try to link a cell from Excel sheet  to a local Html file but to a specific point of the page in the way to not use the scroll but although i directly specific the specific anchor 
=HYPERLINK("file:///C:/Users/report.html#N1BB01-2305843010000002668",("resetaccelarationsensor"))

in the Html code it always directs me to the top of the page :
file:///C:/Users/report.html

sample Html source code :

```
<li>
<img border="0" src="Interaction.gif"> &nbsp;
                <a href="#N1BB01-2305843010000002668">resetAccelerationSensorFault</a>
</li>
```

If i open the html and go the links it directs me perfectly to the information that are linked 
Why or how should i do so the hyperlink directs me exactly to the point in the page that i want from the excel .

Answer (score 1):

Excel hyperlinks do work to bookmarks on a page, like this one:

https://jkp-ads.com/download.asp#Compare2Tables

if the name attribute has been used, like so:

```
<a href="downloadscript.asp?filename=Compare2Tables.zip" name="Compare2Tables">
                    Compare2Tables.zip </a>
```